# How to activate bootstrap tooltip on Element A when interacting with Element B?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am using bootstrap's [tooltip.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/tooltip.js) and want to activate a tooltip on Element A, when interacting (hover / click) with Element B. Right now, I have it set up where interacting with Element A triggers a tooltip on itself, which is fine. But I'm confused on how to trigger that same tooltip with Element B as well. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think Element B should have the same name or id as Element A then call the tooltip for Element B how you have called tooltip for Element A.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not do the trick. Thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#elementB').on('hover', function(){
    $('#elementA').trigger('hover');
});

$('#elementB').on('click', function(){
    $('#elementA').trigger('click');
})
```